# Select2 displays bold text correctly, but when typing, bold becomes the html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using a `Select2` dropdown, and this is the `templateResult` function that I am using when defining the dropdown, in order to apply formatting to the results:

```
templateResult : function (item) {
            if (item.loading) {
                return item.text;
            }
            var term = query.term || '';
            var $result = markMatch('<span class="boldwrap">' + item.text.substring(0, item.text.indexOf(":")) + '</span>' + item.text.substring(item.text.indexOf(":")), term);
            return $result;

        }
```

The `markMatch` function that I have in there, refers to a function I have defined somewhere else, that highlights the search results as you type. That works well and highlights as expected.

My only problem is with the bold text that `$result` is supposed to return.

It works fine and when opening the select menu, you see that the first words (up to the symbol ":") are showing in bold.

The problem is that when I start typing in the search area of the menu, the bold text goes away and you can only see the html tag `<span class... etc...`

How can I do, so the bold text appears not only when opening and browsing the select menu, but also when typing in the search box? I am not sure why with the highlighting function the css class works fine, but with the bold it doesn't.

This is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sx25kLng/) with the issue.

**CLARIFICATION:** I don't want to simply remove the html tags. I want that the text remains bold while searching, without displaying the tags. If you simply remove them, the text is not bold anymore.

**BEFORE/AFTER EXAMPLES:**

When opening the menu and scrolling, the text items should look like this (see fiddle below):

**One:** bla bla bla

**Two:** bla bla bla

**Three:** bla bla bla

Whith my issue, when I start typing in the box, they become:

`<span class="boldwrap">`One:`</span>` bla bla bla

`<span class="boldwrap">`Two:`</span>` bla bla bla

`<span class="boldwrap">`Three:`</span>` bla bla bla

And I would like them to remain like in the first step, with the initial word in bold:

**One:** bla bla bla

**Two:** bla bla bla

**Three:** bla bla bla

The solutions that other users suggested me, just remove the html tags but do not keep the bold text, so with their code, the menu becomes just:

One: bla bla bla

Two: bla bla bla

Three: bla bla bla

Comment: Here You have working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sx25kLng/1/. You have to send only text to `markMatch`, not the whole HTML.

Comment: Thanks @daymosik , but since the html tags are gone, the text is not bold anymore. I still would like to have bold text while typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here You have a working fiddle : `https://jsfiddle.net/sx25kLng/3/`, You inserted html with `.text()` method.

Comment: I have a question about your solution: At the end it achieves the desired result, but there are some cases while the html is visible while you type. Do you know the reason? For example, try to go to your fiddle and type just the letter "O" or maybe just the letter "A", and you will see what I mean.

Comment: It's because of the `<span>` element inside the text, but You should be able to fix it now.

Comment: Thanks, now this is actually perfect. And it was useful to see the difference between both versions.